# Docker Postman ECONNRESET

Tags: python, docker, flask, postman

I'm running a flask rest api on backend/app.py, just trying to return a simple {"message": "Hello World"}. I'm using MacOS

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
#from flask_cors import CORS
from routes.tests import hello_world

app = Flask(__name__)
#CORS(app)

hello_world.create_routes(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When starting with `python app.py` without using docker, a request to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/helloWorld` through Postman works just fine and as supposed but when starting the server from docker I get a

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/helloWorld
Error: read ECONNRESET
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mongo-container:
    image: mongo:7.0.2
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: mongod

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo-container

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

Anyone knows what could be causing this?